# Is there a Feynman-Kac formula for vector-valued Schrödinger operators?

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, differential-equations

Given a vector function
$$f=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)\in L^2(\mathbb R,\mathbb R^n)$$
(for some $n\in\mathbb N$), let us define
$$\Delta f:=(\Delta f_1,\ldots,\Delta f_n),$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator, and let $Q:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a potential taking values in symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. I'm interested in *vector Schrödinger operators* of the form
$$Hf=-\Delta f+Qf,\qquad f\in L^2(\mathbb R,\mathbb R^n).$$

> **Question.** Is there a Feynman-Kac type formula known for $H$'s semigroup in the case where $Q(x)$ is not necessarily diagonal?

(Note: I specify abote that I'm interested in the case where $Q$ is not diagonal; if $Q=\mathrm{diag}(Q_1,\ldots,Q_n)$, then
$$Hf=(-\Delta f_1+Q_1 f_1,\ldots,-\Delta f_1+Q_1 f_1),$$
in which case we can simply apply the one-dimensional Feynman-Kac formula to each component.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the usual formula with the exponential of $Q$ replaced by a [time-ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential) --- needed in the integral over $t$ since $Q[x(t)]$ and $Q[x(t')]$ do not commute for $t\neq t'$. One reference where this "chronological'" integral is worked out is 
[Equivalence of Two Definitions of a Chronological Integral.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3103%2FS002713221006001X.pdf)

Comment: How would the fomula be modified for the more general case where $Hf=-\Delta f + R\nabla f + Qf$, where $R:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^{n\times n}$? Specifically, I'm not sure how the Itô process would be modified since the $\textrm d t$ term now has a matrix coefficient. I can move this to a separate question if necessary.

Comment: I separate question would seem the way to go.